# How do I set return type from method with an Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression, func

I am wanting to call a method with the signiture something like

```
string fullname = UserBuilder.DefaultProperty(e => e.Fullname)
```

I have created a builder class and want to return the default property from a default supplied

```
public class BuilderGeneric<TModel>
{
    private readonly TModel _defaultModel;

    public BuilderGeneric(TModel defaultModel)
    {
        _defaultModel = defaultModel;
    }

    public object DefaultProperty<TProperty>([NotNull] Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        // Reflection here to get the property
        // ...
        var propertyType = myPropInfo.PropertyType;
        var propertyValue = myPropInfo.GetValue(_defaultModel);

        return propertyValue;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that I dont return an object back but instead the type of the property in the `e => e.Fullname)` in that example it would be a string

Comment: It isn't altogether clear how the method works, can you elaborate on what relationship the expression has to the return type?

Comment: Are you simply after `public TProperty DefaultProperty<TProperty>(...)`? You'll need to return `(TProperty)propertyValue` of course

Comment: Also note that you don't necessarily need the "Reflection here to get the property" -- `propertyExpression.Compile()(_defaultModel)` will do it. You don't even need to use an expression for this -- `public TProperty DefaultProperty<TProperty>(Func<TModel, TProperty> propertyGetter) => propertyGetter(_defaultModel);`

Comment: :'( I'm Not sure why I got the negative from the question. I was trying to keep it short and readable and not worry too much about what I was trying to do get the property value but concentrate on returning the correct type

Comment: Thanks @canton7 I had tried to cast it with an as ```propertyValue as TProperty``` which didnt work. Casting it in brackets did Thanks

Comment: Yeah, `TProperty` is an unconstrained generic type, which means it might be a reference or a value type. `as` only works with reference types or `Nullable<T>` -- you can write `o as string` or `o as int?`, but not `o as int`. Since `TProperty` might be an `int`, the compiler can't guarantee that the `as` syntax will work. A normal cast is doesn't have these problems and is fine, though.

Comment: You probably got a downvote because you removed important stuff from `DefaultProperty`, and just left a comment. Don't do that -- give us code which we can run and which demonstrates your error. I had to do some guessing to figure out what you might be asking. You got the "minimal" part of [mcve], but not the "reproducible" part

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @canton7

I was trying to create a generic builder class which I have included below along with a unit test.

I hope this helps anyone trying to to a similar thing.

```
public class BuilderGeneric<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    private readonly TModel _defaultModel;

    private TModel BuilderEntity { get; }

    public BuilderGeneric(TModel defaultModel)
    {
        _defaultModel = defaultModel;
        BuilderEntity = (TModel)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TModel));
    }

    public TProperty DefaultProperty<TProperty>(Func<TModel, TProperty> property)
    {
        return property(_defaultModel);
    }

    public BuilderGeneric<TModel> With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property, TProperty value)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        propertyInfo.SetValue(BuilderEntity, value);

        return this;
    }

    public TModel Build()
    {
        return BuilderEntity;
    }
}

public class UserBuilder : BuilderGeneric<UserProfile>
{
    public UserBuilder()
        : base(new UserProfile()
        {
            FullName = "Ian Bowyer",
            EmailAddress = "Email@Email.com",
            MyGuid = new Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012")
        })
    {
    }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
}

public class TestGenericBuilder
{
    [Test]
    public void TestTheDefaultPropertyReturns()
    {
        // Assert
        var userBuilder = new UserBuilder()
            .With(e => e.FullName, "Bobby Tables")
            .With(e => e.MyGuid, new Guid("85EC85CF-2892-40B8-BF63-0C621F78BE27"));

        var user = userBuilder.Build();

        // Act
        var defaultFullname = userBuilder.DefaultProperty(e => e.FullName);

        // Assert
        defaultFullname.Should().Be("Ian Bowyer");
        user.FullName.Should().Be("Bobby Tables");
    }
}
```